# How to execute stored procedure

Tags: acumatica

I know this is not recommended way by Acumatica, but we don't have other option than to use stored procedure. I have created a new processing screen to execute stored procedure but am facing time out exception.

My code sample is below:

```
using (new PXConnectionScope())
{
  using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
   {
     PXDatabase.Execute("MYSTOREDPROCEDURE", pars.ToArray());
     ts.Complete();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing long running code in `PXLongOperation` context. I assume these establishes a connection with periodic ping to avoid time-out while waiting for data to arrive.

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate()
{
   // Code executed in long operation context
});
```

If your code is executed from the context of a processing delegate I think it should be already wrapped in a long operation though. Otherwise long operation should be used inside an action event handler.

A last recourse would be to increase time-out in the `web.config` file.
Use of stored procedure is a concern mainly for SAAS hosting and obtaining an Acumatica ISV Certification. There's likely no official support for it but I doubt it's gonna go away.