# Get column names of a table from database in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How to get columns from a database table like APTran?

I tried to get from the akumatika cache in this way, but the problem is that what is in the cache and in the database does not always match

```
 Type objType = System.Web.Compilation.PXBuildManager.GetType(e.Row.ObjectName, true);
 PXCache objCache = Base.Caches[objType];
 var fields = objCache.Fields;
```

I only need to get the name of the columns that are in the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a Stored Procedure for this and execute it with

```
 var results = PXDatabase.Execute()
```

see this question [How to execute stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291328/how-to-execute-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this recently for a generic service I needed to implement, and you can accomplish this via reflection.

```
PXCache cache = Base.Caches[objectType];
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

// An array containing every property on the table in the cache.
PropertyInfo[] fields = cache.GetItemType().GetProperties(bindingFlags);

foreach (PropertyInfo field in fields)
{
    object fieldValue = cache.GetValue(record, field.Name);
    // Do something with fieldValue
    // Check what attributes the property has by using field.GetCustomAttributes()
    // If you only want SQL persisted fields you would examine the attributes
    // And see if it contains a PXDBDatatype attribute
}
```

The bindingFlags variable isn't necessary in this case, but I wanted to demonstrate using it as you will need it quite often when retrieving attributes or properties so knowing it exists is important. Hopefully this helped, I would recommend looking up the System.Reflection library and what's available on the PropertyInfo object type to see everything that you would be able to do as a next step but this should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Um..  Don't?  Fields from DAC may well be different than fields from DB (May be More, Less, or Match.  Match is actually fairly rare....)  DB - Do sp_help on the table.  DAC - Here is code I use to display both field and data:

```
StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder();

if (obj != null)
{
    foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
    {
        if (retval.Length > 0) retval.Append(",");
        retval.Append(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}={1}", descriptor.Name, descriptor.GetValue(obj)));
    }
}
return retval.ToString();
```